# CORS Issue, HapiJS HAPI-16

Tags: node.js, cors, axios, hapi.js

### EDIT: That only works for HapiJS 16- versions

I have a client in react and a server using HapiJS.

In the client, I try to make a POST request to the server, but i get the following error

> OPTIONS http://localhost:3001/sentilize/ 404 (Not Found) localhost/:1
>   Failed to load http://localhost:3001/sentilize/: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I am running the server on port 3001. And I am running the client on 3000.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated. Also, I can successfully make post requests to the server using POSTMAN. It's just from React that it doesn't work.

Here is my server.js

```html
import Hapi from "hapi";
import { routes } from "./routes";

const server = Hapi.server({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3001,
  routes: { cors: true }
});

// Register Routes
routes.forEach(route => {
  server.route(route);
});

// We need to install babel-polyfill
// because async and await are in es7
async function start() {
  try {
    await server.start();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("Hapii server is running");
}

start();
```

Here is the code that makes the call, on the front end

```html
  fetchSentiment = () => {
    axios
      .post("/", {
        sentence: this.state.value
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ sentiment: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
      });
  };
```

I have an axios instance setup as follows (axios-sentiment.js)

```html
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001/sentilize"
});

export default instance;
```

Comment: Postman won't give you a cors error, that's normal.

Comment: cors: { origin: ['allowedhostnamehere'] }

Comment: And why is your cors setting inside routes?

Comment: That doesn't work :(... where else would i put it?

Comment: Use cors enable extention it will work in google chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The server configuration looks correct. It's possible that the client HTTP library in use is not sending the correct headers. In particular, make sure that the request has the `Origin` header. Note that the `cors: true` setting only supports certain CORS scenarios and will not work in every situation. Read about [simplified requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Examples_of_access_control_scenarios) to understand some of the nuances of CORS. Then the [route.options.cors](https://hapijs.com/api#-routeoptionscors) documentation will make more sense and you can set it as an object to tweak its behavior, if necessary.

Some other, unrelated tips:

- `async` `await` is supported in Node 7.6 and up. You probably don't need babel or babel-polyfill at all. See [node.green](http://node.green/) to learn which language features are supported.
- Try / catching a Promise chain just to log the error is an old pattern that shouldn't be used anymore. Promise errors used to be swallowed by default, but they aren't anymore, they are logged by modern versions of Node (and browsers, too). If you want to be even more aggressive, you can use [throw-rejects](https://github.com/sholladay/throw-rejects) to also intentionally crash the process rather than just logging, which makes it even easier to find mistakes.

Comment: Thank you Seth! Unfortunately I get a compilation error saying options are not allowed when i try this .. AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid server options {
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3001,
  "routes": {},
  "options" [1]: {
    "routes": {
      "cors": true
    }
  }
}

[1] "options" is not allowed

Comment: same here @Asool, I had to setup it on my route config, I could't set it in initial http config.

Comment: @felipekm  What does that syntax look like?  I am looking in my hapi.js In Action book and not seeing that option.

Comment: Oops!  I lied. Page 261 has the answer:      server.route([
        {
            config: { cors: true },
   method: 'GET',
            path: '/{param*}',

Comment: Note that the structure of the server API and configuration has changed between [hapi 16](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/28ea8fa9f7816ad07156ee0ff20df30960a04552/API.md) and [hapi v17](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/ea5a4db1c773cf52643888dc347fa1c348254d5c/API.md#server()). I'm hapi to take a deeper look if someone can post a CodeSandbox that reproduces the problem.